# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.flush.SyncedFlushRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am migrating from elasticSearch 6.4 to 8.82 and i am trying to run rest high level client on compatibility mode but getting the error. AnyBody has any idea , how can i resolve this error.
Getting error on this line:
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClientBuilder(restClientBuilder.build())
.setApiCompatibilityMode(true)
.build();
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.flush.SyncedFlushRequest at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) site:stackoverflow.com

please help to resolve this

Comment: Are both your client and Elasticsearch server using the exact same version, i.e. 8.8.2 ?

Comment: @val High level client 8.8.2 is no available thats why trying to run high level client in api compatibility mode with high level client version 7.17.11

Comment: So you've implemented what is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/migrate-hlrc.html), right?

Comment: @Val yes exactly the same